# MissingRuntimeArtifactException while changing IEnumerable to IQueryable in Universal Windows

Tags: c#, windows-10, win-universal-app, .net-4.6

In Release mode, while changing the IEnumerable source to IQueryable using AsQueryable method which throws System.Reflection.MissingRuntimeArtifactException. This is code is working fine in Debug mode, please refer the below code snippet.

```
    ObservableCollection<object> data;
    IEnumerable source;
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        data = new ObservableCollection<object>();
        source = data as IEnumerable;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var querab1 = data.AsQueryable();
        var querab2 = source.AsQueryable();
    }
```

Is there any solution for this exception?

Answer (score 2):

Add the following line to the `<Application>` node in your runtime directives file (usually called `Default.rd.xml` and found in the `Properties` folder).

```
<Namespace Name="System.Linq" Dynamic="Required All" Serialize="Required All" XmlSerializer="Required All"/>
```

Using the Release mode invokes the .NET Native tool chain. It includes in the final app assembly only that code that is actually invoked by the app. This causes certain reflection and late-bound invocation code to not be included in your app. Using the runtime directives file allows you to override the default behavior and include the required metadata and implementation code.

PS: Your runtime directives file should look something like this:

```
<Directives xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2013/01/metadata">
  <Application>
    <Assembly Name="*Application*" Dynamic="Required All" />
    <Namespace Name="System.Linq" Dynamic="Required All" Serialize="Required All" XmlSerializer="Required All" />
  </Application>
</Directives>
```

Comment: Hi Lukkha, Thanks for the solution. I had a custom control and in my source, there is no rd.xml file but this solution works fine when I add it in sample. Is there any solution to fix this issue in code behind? Than would be more helpful for me.

Comment: Hi @LukkhaCoder, Same exception has been raised while using extension method for IQueryable, the above solution is working for changing IEnumerable to IQueryable. But while using extension method, it throws error, Could you please share any solution for this error?

Comment: Which namespace does the extension method belong do?

Comment: Thanks Lukkha, the above solution works fine. But I am facing another problem, please refer this link http://bit.ly/1NLk7uZ

Comment: Having overly broad directives will cause your application to be larger than necessary (and inflating build times). There's also cases where this will cause the Serialization generator to needlessly crash during compilation. We don't recommend adding serialization (Serialize/XmlSerialize) tags unless you really really need them.